# How to block a common user use startx command?

Tags: 14.04, xorg

How can I block a common user use startx command when he login? And leave just root user use startx after login?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "root user"? **root** should never start an X session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The propably simplest way is to change the ownership of the startx binary (normally in /usr/bin/startx) in a way that only the owner (root) can execute that file. You can do this e.g. by entering `sudo chmod 0744 /usr/bin/startx` into a terminal.